# How to get the sum of rows group by rows

Tags: sql-server

```
;With T(days,currentvalue)  
AS
(
SELECT a.days,sum(counts) as currentvalue from SUMOP A
group by days
)
Update SUMOP set sumop.currentvalue=T.currentvalue
where sumop.days=T.days
```

Above query is throwing error. Is there any syntax error? Please help

I'm getting this error while executing the query:

```
The multi-part identifier "T.days" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Helps if you show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a semicolon before `with` and update with join.

```
; With T(days,currentvalue)  
AS
(
SELECT a.days,sum(counts) as currentvalue from SUMOP A
group by days
)
Update SUMOP set sumop.currentvalue=T.currentvalue
FROM SUMOP, T where sumop.days=T.days
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "T.days" could not be bound.

Comment: @user3540150 Edited, now try

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to calculate the sum of `counts` for each day:

```
update  t
set     currentvalue = t.curval
from    (
        select  currentvalue
        ,       sum(counts) over (partition by days) as curval
        from    sumop
        ) t
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe988/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Your CTE T creates a rowset, so you need to update from a join.